# How to avoid imported css overwrite other css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, compass-sass

The `@import "compass";` overwrites the

```
*= require_tree ../lenord-single-page-theme/css
*= require_tree ../ace-admin-theme/css
```

How could I import @compass without overwrite other css files ?

application.css

```
@import "compass";

/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree ../lenord-single-page-theme/css
 *= require_tree ../ace-admin-theme/css
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```